# Using scripts in Google Sheets on Android Device

Tags: android, google-sheets

I would like to create a simple kind of cash register app on android coupled with google sheets. This way we can get an overview of the orders which come in on a laptop near the place we serve the drinks.

My current problem is that I can not find any possibility to start a script from an android device in google sheets apart from a script that reacts onEdit.

Is there anybody that can give me a clue on how I should try to solve this issue?

FYI the cash register system is for a small fund raiser of our gild.

Comment: This question does not fit the StackOverflow's rules because it's too broad and will attract only opinion based answers (so expect it to be closed). Please, go to the: http://stackoverflow.com/help, then read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Custom functions will work well in Android.

Comment: @Anonymous
Thank you for the useful tip.